# error when accessing environment variables in leiningen project.clj with environ

Tags: clojure, leiningen, environ

I'm trying -- and failing -- to use environ 1.2.0 to create environment variables for codox inside project.clj.

I have in profiles.clj
`{:dev {:env {:doc-dir "/home/me/some/dir"}}}`

So far all good: `.line-env` is correctly created and I can pull the value in a repl.
However I cannot get the value inside project.clj

```
(defproject ....

  :codox {:output-path (environ.core/env :doc-dir) })
```

I get an error from `lein codox`:

```
Syntax error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling at (/tmp/form-init13693313479173922228.clj:1:74). 
No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

codox works if I remove the call to environ.core.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem by looking at the source of codox.

When the plugin pulls the map of the project, it reads without interpreting,
so the output path isn't set to the environment value but to the form `(environ.core/env :doc-dir)`

However, since the goal is to move the codox parameters to a separate file that git can ignore, the right way to do it is simply to put the :codox section, with hardcoded values, inside the dev profile in `profiles.clj`. Codox looks into the profiles as well as into the project.

Answer (score 1):

I use `codox` frequently, but normally just accept the default output dir.  I tried an experiment as follows:

```
  ; Using `lein-ancient check :all` checks plugins
  :plugins [
            [lein-codox "0.10.7"]
            [com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.24.1"]]

  :codox {:src-dir-uri                "http://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/"
          :src-linenum-anchor-prefix  "L"
          :source-paths               ["src/clj" "src/cljc"]
          :language                   :clojure
          :namespaces                 [#"^tupelo\."]
          :exclude-vars               #".*IntervalClosed|.*SpliceItem|map->[A-Z].*"
          :output-path                "docs/out/codox" }
```

Note that this works on Java11 (OpenJDK11) but fails on Java17 with a module/reflection error.

Do you really need `environ` for use with `codox`?
If you need to deploy the resulting webpage to different locations depending on the host, I would just create a short shell script using (even easier using `scp` instead of `cp`) and put in some `if` tests to determine the destination.

Comment: you are right, I don't need  `environ`. but see answer below for the right way to do it.